# SSIS: To run the package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install expression task of integration services or higher

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2014

Me and my colleague using the same version of .Net framework (4.5) and installed SSDT in visual studio 2013. He prepared a package (not so complex) and can able to execute the same from SSDT without any issue. He imported the package to the integration services under MSDB for testing. If he 'Run package' from integration services he gets an error stating that "To run the package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install expression task of integration services or higher".
If I tried to execute by clicking 'Run package' from integration services (MSDB) which he imported; I can able to execute it without any issues.

We have verified all the installation and everything looks similar. Can you guys help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score -1):

When you run the package from msdb it executes on the machine that you are running it from.

(Unlike packages stored in the 2012+ SSISDB catalog where executing them spawns an execution process on the Server itself).

You must have installed SQL Server Integration Services onto your own machine from the SQL Server installation media, whereas your colleague hasn't. If Integration Services isn't installed you are restricted to running packages in SSDT. Executing packages that run locally with dtexecui will fail.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just found that I have SQL Server integration service 12.0 installed in my machine and he has SQL Server Integration service 10.0 installed. Asked him to install 12.0 version now; hope that will solve this issue.